# Using service on route configuration on Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

i have to restrict the access to a state if I haven't something started.

I have:

#### App -> InitService (factory)

```
// ...
var started = false;

var start = function () {
    asyncStart()
       .then(function () {
           started = true;
       });
};

var isStarted = function () {
    return started;
};

return {
    start: start,
    isStarted: isStarted
};

//...
```

#### App -> Run

```
//...
    $stateProvider

        .state('welcome',
            url: '/welcome',
            controller: 'WelcomeCtr',
            template: welcomeTemplate
         })

         .state('app', {
            url: '/app',
            abstract: true,
            controller: 'AppCtr',
            template: appTemplate,
            resolve: {
                security: [
                     '$q',
                     'InitService',
                      function ($q, InitService) {
                          if (!InitService.isStarted()) {
                              return $q.reject(new Error("Is not started"));
                          }
                      }
                ]
            }
         })

    ;
//...
```

When I run the app, I have this error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module App due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module App due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: InitService
```

I think it's because the module.run, runs before the services factories definition. If so, how should I do to inject the service after *module.run* load?

There is a more correct way?

Sorry my poor enlgish.

Comment: Can you please post the code where you wire the services together? If you're trying to access a service that hasn't been registered yet - there's no way angular can use it.

Comment: It's not because the order, I tried using a property in $rootScope, and in bootstrap (with module.run()) can't access to it. I resolve it using a global var.

Comment: I'd be wary of using global variables altogether. Is it possible to use event listeners on the $rootScope instead? Also is it bootstrap css? Or angular.bootstrap?

Comment: Not is possible to use $rootScope, I say "bootstrap" to the _module.config()_ where I configure the routes (sorry by the confusion), I tried to require $rootScope and I can't.I hate the globals to, but it's a temporary solution to this works. I hope to find the good way to do it.